# Patrones de diseño en una página para webmail entre usuarios registrados

Tags: php, mysql, patrones-de-diseño

Estoy pensando cuál sería una forma viable para crear una página "webmail" entre usuarios registrados con JavaScript/PHP/etc.

Tenía pensado almacenar las credenciales de los usuarios que se registran en una base de datos y que, si los usuarios desean enviarse mails/mensajes, dichos mensajes serían almacenados en una tabla con un `id del remitente` y el `id del destinatario`.

Entonces, suponiendo que el usuario 'A' le manda un mail/mensaje al usuario 'B',
la tabla sería de la siguiente manera:

```
ID_DESTINATARIO   |   ID_REMITENTE   |   CONTENIDO_MENSAJE/MAIL
```

Por ende cuando el usuario B se loguee, o se actualice la información de su correo, se haría una consulta a la base de datos por ejemplo:

```sql
SELECT CONTENIDO_MENSAJE/MAIL 
  FROM TABLA_CORREO
 WHERE ID_DESTINATARIO='ID_DEL_QUE_SE_LOGUEA'
```

De esta manera, el usuario 'A' vería todos los correos que tienen como `ID_DESTINATARIO` su id.

¿Es este un patrón de diseño viable? ¿Debería encarar el diseño de mi aplicación de otra forma totalmente diferente a como lo estoy pensando? ¿Y es correcto pensar en el uso de una base de datos para este escenario?, porque no sé si no es muy lento y costoso utilizar una base de datos para este tipo de páginas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu descripción de la *arquitectura* con que piensas hacer la **App** no la veo mal. No pienses que una **base de datos** es lenta o costosa. Si quieres almacenar grandes cantidades de datos y acceder a ellos de manera eficiente, usa **base de datos**.

> Pero sí es importante el diseño y la implementación de la **base de
>   datos**.

Answer (score 0):

Casi todo lo que indicas en la descripción son detalles de implementación. Utilizar bases de datos, archivos, vectores en memoria o lo que sea no es más que la implementación de un sistema.

El diseño es todo lo anterior a eso, cuáles son los comportamientos, qué componentes existen, qué objetos interactúan, cuales son los escenarios de acción, casos de prueba, etc.

Para estructurar el sistema diseñado, y mejorarlo, hacerlo fácil de mantener y extender se utilizan patrones de diseño, prácticas como principios de diseño y otros.